# JSF CommandLink does not work on Firefox after a whole form reRender

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, richfaces

I have a JSF 1.2 application (Sun RI, Facelets, Richfaces) that was used only on IE6 browsers. Now, we must also support Firefox (yeah !).

In one of my pages, I have a form that contains a button that will re-render the whole form. After the re-rendering, some links (`<h:commandLink/>`) are added in this form.

The JSF code looks like this:

```
<h:form id="foobar">
    ...
    <a4j:commandButton ... reRender="foobar"/>
    ...
    <h:commandLink .../>
</h:form>
```

My problem is related to the HTML code generated by the command link component, which is as following:

```
<a href="#" onclick="if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){jsfcljs(document.forms['foobar'],'...','');}return false">bla bla</a>
```

(for information, `jsfcljs` is the Javascript function generated by the component `<h:commandLink/>`)

The problem is that `document.forms["foobar"]` is working well when the page is initially rendered, but once the form is re-rendered after the Ajax call, this code does not work anymore on Firefox (but works on IE6).

This results on a Javascript error when I click on one link in the form after the Ajax call.

Note that if I call `document.getElementById("foobar");` after the Ajax call, Firefox founds my form...

If you consider the following Javascript function:

```
function test() {
    var e = document.forms;
    var tmp = "";
    for (i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
        tmp = tmp + e[i].id + " ; ";
    }
    alert(tmp);
}
```

when I run it before and after the Ajax call, I get the following results:

```
someForm ; anotherForm ; foobar ; // Before Ajax call on FF 
someForm ; anotherForm ; // After Ajax call on FF. PROBLEM HERE!

someForm ; anotherForm ; foobar ; // Before Ajax call on IE6 
someForm ; anotherForm ; foobar ; // After Ajax call on IE6
```

Here are my thoughts about the reason of the problem:

When the Ajax response is received on the client side, a4j is removing the *reRender*-ed elements (in particular my `foobar` form) from the DOM tree objects, which results in removing it from `document.forms` array.
Then, it adds again the `foobar` form with its new content. But Firefox does **not** update the `document.forms` array, while IE6 does.
That's why `document.forms["foobar"]` returns `undefined` after the Ajax call.

My solution to solve this problem is to change the `reRender` attribute in order to re-render only sub-parts of the form, and not the form itself. This way, my links work.

However, I wanted to know if there is another way to solve this issue, without modifying the `reRender` attribute.
Any idea?

---

*Edit*

The Javascript code when a command link is clicked is the following:

```
function dpf(f) {
    var adp = f.adp;
    if (adp != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < adp.length; i++) {
            f.removeChild(adp[i]);
        }
    }
};

function apf(f, pvp) {
    var adp = new Array();
    f.adp = adp;
    var ps = pvp.split(',');
    for (var i = 0, ii = 0; i < ps.length; i++, ii++) {
        var p = document.createElement("input");
        p.type = "hidden";
        p.name = ps[i];
        p.value = ps[i + 1];
        f.appendChild(p);
        adp[ii] = p;
        i += 1;
    }
};

function jsfcljs(f, pvp, t) {
    apf(f, pvp);
    var ft = f.target;
    if (t) {
        f.target = t;
    }
    f.submit();
    f.target = ft;
    dpf(f);
};
```

In the `<h:commandLink>` onclick attribute, we call the `jsfcljs(document.forms['foobar'], 'someId', '')` which is evaluated in `jsfcljs(undefined, 'someId', '')`. Then, when `f` is called, I get a Javacript error that says that `f is undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is actually an HTML one from what I see.

Your form should be defined with a name and not simply an id attribute:

Different browsers treat name and id equivalencies differently.  If this does not solve your problem comment and I will produce a test case that does not require a server-side to demonstrate whatever effect you're seeing.

Another way around the problem code is to rewrite the inline onclick event calls on the client-side in order to reference the form by id with the document.getElementById("foobar") call instead of document.forms["foobar"]

Comment: Thanks for the idea of using the `name` in addition to the `id` attribute. I will check that soon!
Regarding your proposition to modify the inline `onclick` function, it is not conceivable, as this JS code is *generated* by the JSF core. However, as stated by **BalusC**, this code has maybe evolved since the latest release of JSF 1.2...

Comment: The functions can be modified by other javascript code embedded in the page.  If it turns out that is necessary, I can likely provide code that accomplishes this task.

Comment: I have a similar problem with Chrome doing a rerender but Firefox refusing to rerender. Adding a `name` to the form didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I recall this as one of the bugs of Sun Mojarra 1.2 (which has already been around for 4 years). Upgrading the libs should solve this problem. The currently latest Sun Mojarra 1.2 is [1.2_14](http://javaserverfaces.dev.java.net) which was released just three weeks ago. Just replace the two JSF libs in `/WEB-INF/lib` with them.